# Power when exponent is i

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Suppose we compute $z=3^i$.
$$3^i=(3*1)^i=3^i*(e^{2\pi ni})^i=3^i*e^{-2\pi n}\Rightarrow 3^i*(1-e^{-2\pi n})=0\Rightarrow 3^i=0,\textrm{ if }n\neq 0$$

So is $z=0$ a solution too ?

Comment: $(e^{2\pi i n})^{i}$ is not a well defined complex number.

Comment: *Ex falso, quodlibet*. In your case, you’re applying the properties $(xy)^z=x^zy^z$ and $x^{yz}=(x^y)^z$ that cannot hold for complex numbers. Why can’t them? Well, your argument shows it.

Comment: Potentially, what you've actually shown is that in order to apply the exponential properties you've used, we must have $n=0$ (slightly more technically, you may have implicitly chosen the branch of the logarithm corresponding to $n=0$)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way: Write $$3^{i}=e^{\ln 3^i}= e^{i \ln 3}= \cos(\ln 3)+i \sin (\ln 3).$$

In your step $3^{i}$ remains as it is, you have made no progress.